# jQuery .on() event on specified element

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have following javascript code

```
$(document).on('click', $('#contact-list li'), function (e) {
```

The list is dynamically created and I need the clicked list item (li) in my function for his/her attributes so first I tried

```
$(e.target)
```

but that was the exact element clicked on inside the li. The parent of the parent of the parent

```
$(e.target).parent()...;
```

will eventually get me to the li but I can't seem to find a better way. Sorry in advance if there is an obvious answer.

Comment: Is `.parents('li')` what you're looking for? http://api.jquery.com/parents/ Or perhaps `e.currentTarget`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.closest('li')` to get the `<li>` in question.

http://api.jquery.com/closest

---

Don't pass a jQuery object to `.on()`, just the selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '#contact-list li', callback);
```

and if the element with ID `contact-list` exists when you're binding events, this will work:

```
$('#contact-list').on('click', 'li', callback);
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 0):

`$(e.target).closest('li')` will return the item if it's a `li`, or the closest parent that matches the query.

Answer (score 0):

If the click is occurring on an LI element, which is what you are trying to do with your jQuery statement, then the $(this) reference will allow you to access that object. The .closest() suggested by everyone is unnecessary.

```
$(document).on('click', '#contact-list li', function (e) {
    console.log($(this));
}
```

Fiddle me this: http://jsfiddle.net/sytac5zg/